# i want to know why it wont print whenever i write to a buffer

Tags: c, file-io

i'm trying to understand why i can't write to a buffer, read from a buffer, and write it to another file;

```
int main()
{
    int fd, fz;
    char *buff;
    fd = open("./text", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0644);
    fz = open("./text2", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0644);
    buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
    write(fd, "it works\n", 300);
    read(fd, buff, 300);
    close(fd);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff,300);
    write(fz, buff, 300);

    close(fz);

    return (0);
}
```

i wanted it to write "it works" to the file, send it to a buffer. print it to a console and write it in another file.

Comment: `write(fd, "it works\n", 300)` invokes undefined behaviour. Do not try to write more bytes than you have. **Always** check the return value of all system library functions.

Comment: `open()`, `write()`, `read()` and `close()` are not standard C functions. From where do you get this functions? I assume it is POSIX? If so, please mention it and don't forget to include the necessary headers. If it is POSIX, check the return value of `open()`, `write()` and `read()`, because they can fail (always think about possible errors and how to handle them. POSIX `close()` can also fail but there is not much you can do about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least following problems in your code:

- you blindly write/read 300 bytes, although length of the string you write is only 9 (length of the `"it works\n"` string).
- you don't position the file pointer to the start of the file after having written to it.
- you don't do any error checking.

You probably want something like this:

```
#include whatever you included

#include <string.h>   // for strlen

int main()
{
    const char *itworks ="it works\n";
    int fd, fz;
    char *buff;
    fd = open("./text", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0644);
    fz = open("./text2", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0644);
    buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);

    write(fd, itworks, strlen(itworks));   // don't write more bytes than you have
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);                // positon file pointer to start
    int bytesread = read(fd, buff, 300);   // bytesread will contain the number of
                                           // bytes actually read           
    close(fd);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, bytesread); // only write the number of bytes
    write(fz, buff, bytesread);            //   actually read

    close(fz);

    return 0;   // OT don't put return values between (), it's not wrong
                // but just strange and unusual
}
```

Discalaimer: there is still no error checking, the `open` function can easily fail. So can `read` and `write`, but they are much less likely to fail.